# How to handle downloading in GeckoFX 29

Tags: c#, .net, gecko, xulrunner, geckofx

How can I handle downloading in **GeckoFx** I'm using version **29**
I've found some ways like adding event of
`LauncherDialog_Download(object sender, LauncherDialogEvent e)`
But, I'm not able to **add handler** for this event

I tried this for handler

```
LauncherDialogFactory.Register();
LauncherDialog.Download += LauncherDialog_Download;
```

But, it is showing as error, how can i add handler
and is there any other ways to handle downloading in **GeckoFx 29**?

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: for LauncherDialogFactory.Register(), namespace could not be found
and for LauncherDialog.Download += LauncherDialog_Download, is 'event' but is used like 'type'

Comment: You need to include proper namespaces to use this functionality

Comment: which namespace? i've included namespace of Gecko! any other i'm missing?

Answer (score 5):

In form load after your

```
browser.navigate("http://www.domain.com");
```

Use this:

```
LauncherDialog.Download += LauncherDialog_Download;
```

Create LauncherDialog_Download

```
void LauncherDialog_Download(object sender, LauncherDialogEvent e)
    {
        nsILocalFile objTarget = Xpcom.CreateInstance<nsILocalFile>("@mozilla.org/file/local;1");

        using (nsAString tmp = new nsAString(@Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\temp.tmp"))
        {
            objTarget.InitWithPath(tmp);
        }

        //Save file dialog
        Stream myStream;
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = e.Filename;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                nsIURI source = IOService.CreateNsIUri(e.Url);
                nsIURI dest = IOService.CreateNsIUri(new Uri(@saveFileDialog1.FileName).AbsoluteUri);
                nsAStringBase t = (nsAStringBase)new nsAString(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(@saveFileDialog1.FileName));

                nsIWebBrowserPersist persist = Xpcom.CreateInstance<nsIWebBrowserPersist>("@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1");
                nsIDownloadManager DownloadMan = null;
                DownloadMan = Xpcom.CreateInstance<nsIDownloadManager>("@mozilla.org/download-manager;1");
                nsIDownload download = DownloadMan.AddDownload(0, source, dest, t, e.Mime, 0, null, (nsICancelable)persist, false);

                if (download != null)
                {
                    persist.SetPersistFlagsAttribute(2 | 32 | 16384);
                    persist.SetProgressListenerAttribute((nsIWebProgressListener)download);
                    persist.SaveURI(source, null, null, null, null, (nsISupports)dest, null);
                }

                myStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code also triggers saveFileDialog so your program will ask where you want to save the file.

Tested and working with GeckoFX 31 and 33 but should work in 29 as well.
If it doesn't, download the latest GeckoFX [from here.](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-33.0)

And Xulrunner [from here.](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/)

Comment: I know this is not a place to ask a question (and I've submitted a new question according to rules) but I cannot miss an opportunity to ask you this: How can I catch an event of uploading a file using Geckofx? Is there any event handler similar to Gecko.LauncherDialog.Download for uploading files?

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
 private void LauncherDialog_Download(object sender, Gecko.LauncherDialogEvent e)
 {
     SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

     saveFileDialog1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
     saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
     saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
     saveFileDialog1.FileName = e.Filename;

     if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         nsILocalFile objTarget = Xpcom.CreateInstance<nsILocalFile>("@mozilla.org/file/local;1");

         using(nsAString tmp = new nsAString(saveFileDialog1.FileName))
         {
             objTarget.InitWithPath(tmp);
         }
         e.HelperAppLauncher.SaveToDisk(objTarget, false);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan's solution doesn't work with geckoFX 45 - it seems they changed some of the libraries and deprecated the download manager. Here is the same event snippet updated to work with GeckoFX 45

```
    private void LauncherDialog_Download(object sender, Gecko.LauncherDialogEvent e)
    {
        nsILocalFile objTarget = Xpcom.CreateInstance<nsILocalFile>("@mozilla.org/file/local;1");

        using (nsAString tmp = new nsAString(@Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\temp.tmp"))
        {
            objTarget.InitWithPath(tmp);
        }

        //Save file dialog
        Stream myStream;
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = e.Filename;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                nsIURI source = IOService.CreateNsIUri(e.Url);
                nsIURI dest = IOService.CreateNsIUri(new Uri(@saveFileDialog1.FileName).AbsoluteUri);
                nsAStringBase t = (nsAStringBase)new nsAString(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(@saveFileDialog1.FileName));

                nsIWebBrowserPersist persist = Xpcom.CreateInstance<nsIWebBrowserPersist>("@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1");

                nsITransfer nst = Xpcom.CreateInstance<nsITransfer>("@mozilla.org/transfer;1");
                nst.Init(source, dest, t, e.Mime, 0, null, persist, false);

                if (nst != null)
                {
                    persist.SetPersistFlagsAttribute(2 | 32 | 16384);
                    persist.SetProgressListenerAttribute((nsIWebProgressListener)nst);
                    persist.SaveURI(source, null, null, (uint)Gecko.nsIHttpChannelConsts.REFERRER_POLICY_NO_REFERRER, null, null, (nsISupports)dest, null);
                }

                myStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```