# How to handle downloading in GeckoFX 60

Tags: vb.net, geckofx, windowsformshost

I have Jason Shuler's solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38058475/10707700) running on GeckoFX `45.0.34`, now I want to update my application to GeckoFX version `60.0.22`, but the line:

```
nsILocalFile objTarget = Xpcom.CreateInstance<nsILocalFile>("@mozilla.org/file/local;1");
```

fails, because the `Gecko.nsILocalFile` object does not exist, 
How do I update the previous line to work in GeckoFX version `60.0.22`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `nsIFile` instead of `nsILocalFile`

for more information see [this geckofx issue](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-60.0/issues/18/nsilocalfile-unkwown)

Comment: Already test it, `nsIFile` works in Gecko version `45` and `60`, thanks.